# UDP with netcat on Mac OS

Tags: macos, udp, netcat

I try to connect to a Tello drone from my Mac by opening an UDP connection to 192.168.10.1 via port 8889 to send commands and receive ack's from the device.

When using "Packet Sender" it works, but the tool is a little clumsy, so I would like to just use netcat, using `nc -4u 192.168.10.1 8889`, but this does not work. Also tried with iperf and gnu netcat, to no avail - iPerf returns a "connection refused". Ping to 192.168.10.1 does work.

Since Packet Sender does work instantly, I assume there is no firewall or general connectivity issue here but I am not sure whether I need to tell nc anything more than the IP and port? The mac is connected to the LAN via Ethernet and to the drone via WLAN, but that does not seem to be a problem for PacketSender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Tello wants CRLF as line-ending, in the apple version of netcat it is activated with `-c`

`/usr/bin/nc -vv -u -c -p 8890 192.168.10.1 8889`

In other versions of netcat the syntax changes and is usually `-C`
for example in kali:

`netcat -vv -u -C -p 8890 192.168.10.1 8889`

Note that in the version of netcat installed with homebrew there is no `-C` option